# exclude images referenced in css from webpack

Tags: css, webpack

I am tying to use webpack on my .css file. 
but I would like it to exclude (dont to work on) any images that the .css file references.

i.e. background-image: url(../images/icon_check.png); should have nothing done to it.

in my webpack.config.js looks like

```
"use strict";
module.exports = {
entry: {
    index: "./src/main/webapp/core/index.js",
    login: "./src/main/webapp/core/login.js",
    siteEditorAdmin: "./src/main/webapp/core/siteEditorAdmin.js"
},
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/main/webapp/core/scripts",
    filename: "[name].js"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        // Extract css files
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader'
        } // IMAGES
    ]
},
amd: { jQuery: true },
devtool: "eval-source-map"
};
```

if I dont have the 2nd loader I get a error that I need a loader.

if I have the 2nd loader,  the error goes away. but the images are created/hashed and the js file is updated to point to them.
i.e. 26c2a65f93c5caaf24ea5bc44d779d33.png

```
eval("module.exports = __webpack_require__.p + \"26c2a65f93c5caaf24ea5bc44d779d33.png\ ....
```

I would really like the js file to look like

```
eval("module.exports = __webpack_require__.p + \"/images/icon_check.png\....
```

I tried a exclude: /.png$/, in the 1st loader. Got no error. but the new image is created and the js is updated to point to the new image.

I know there could be a relative path problem. but that I can fix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do this using `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, my config looks like this:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules here
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [{
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: { url: false }
          }]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/main.css')
   ]
};
```

Please note that my approach is to load all CSS files as imports inside the JS modules themselves, I don't know if this fits your needs.

Anyway perhaps you can get a useful hint with this example.

Answer (score 2):

seems like I got it fixed.

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
            loader: require.resolve("file-loader") + "?name=../[path][name].[ext]"
        }
```

I tried it without the require.resolve but go a error. this will put the file in the path with the same name as it had